Telegram bot doesn't respond to commands
The Telegram bot does not respond to commands. According to the logs, the webhook is installed normally, the bot is launched. But it completely ignores any messages in the bot, logs nothing. Can you please help me to figure out what the problem is?
import telebot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, CallbackQuery
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from flask import Flask, request, abort

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Your token
TOKEN = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"
# Use the full URL of the webhook provided by Make
WEBHOOK_URL = "YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL"

# Create a bot object
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Handler for the /start command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    logger.info(f"Received /start command from user {message.from_user.id}")

    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Choose time", callback_data='choose_time'))

    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Hello! This bot will send you a word and its definition once a day. Choose a time when it will be convenient for you to read and remember it!",
        reply_markup=keyboard
    )

# Function to determine the user's time zone
def get_user_timezone(message):
    # Get UTC time from the message timestamp
    utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(message.date, tz=timezone.utc)
    
    # Determine the offset from UTC in hours
    user_time = utc_time.astimezone()
    offset_seconds = user_time.utcoffset().total_seconds()
    offset_hours = int(offset_seconds // 3600)
    
    user_timezone = f"UTC{'+' if offset_hours >= 0 else ''}{offset_hours}"
    return user_timezone

# Handler for inline buttons
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call: CallbackQuery):
    logger.info(f"Button pressed with callback data: {call.data}")

    if call.data == 'choose_time':
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Morning", callback_data='morning'))
        keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Afternoon", callback_data='afternoon'))
        keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Evening", callback_data='evening'))
        keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Night", callback_data='night'))
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            text="Choose the time of day:",
            reply_markup=keyboard
        )

    elif call.data in ['morning', 'afternoon', 'evening', 'night']:
        times = {
            'morning': ["06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00"],
            'afternoon': ["12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00"],
            'evening': ["18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"],
            'night': ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00"]
        }
        chosen_times = times[call.data]
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for time in chosen_times:
            keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(time, callback_data=f"time_{time}"))
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            text="Choose a specific time:",
            reply_markup=keyboard
        )

    elif call.data.startswith('time_'):
        chosen_time = call.data.split('_')[1]
        
        # Get the user's time zone
        user_timezone = get_user_timezone(call.message)
        
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            text=f"You chose the time {chosen_time}, {user_timezone}"
        )

# Create a Flask object
app = Flask(__name__)

# Flask route for handling webhooks
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    logger.info("Received a webhook request to Flask app")
    logger.info(f"Headers: {request.headers}")
    
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        logger.debug(f"Received JSON string: {json_string}")
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        logger.debug(f"Update object: {update}")
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        logger.info("Update processed successfully by Flask app")
        return 'OK', 200
    else:
        logger.warning("Invalid request received by Flask app")
        abort(400)

# Set the webhook when the app starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL)
    webhook_info = bot.get_webhook_info()
    logger.info(f"Webhook info: {webhook_info}")

    logger.info("Webhook set. Bot started.")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8443)


Can you double check your Webhook URL works? Also, I can see that your app is set to run on 0.0.0.0:8443, does your Webhook URL redirect requests to this endpoint?

The reason was that I tried to use webhook created by Make. It's not allowed to use webhooks for two endpoints.
When I changed Make webhook url to another – bot started
